# Opencart: Cannot update order programmatically

Tags: php, opencart

I'm developing a payment gateway extension on Opencart. The extension is all completed and working fine as planned.

One thing does not seem to be working which is updating order.

I'm trying to update the order as follows:

```
$this->load->model('checkout/order');       
$this->model_checkout_order->update($orderid, 2, 'Processing', true);
```

The `$orderid` variable contains a valid order id, the record can also be found in database, but it is not updating the order. Am I missing something here ?

Opencart ver. 1.5.x

Thank you

Comment: you have missed "r" in "$orderid" check it. if i am rite it should be like following $this->model_checkout_order->update($orderid, 2, 'Processing', true);

Comment: thanks @ManigandanArjunan for pointing, but that was just a typo while typing question here. Actual code is fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have got the solution to this problem. Adding here for the information.

I was missing "confirm" API at the first place. It has to be confirmed first, otherwise it won't be updated.

```
// 2 is for status 'Processing'
$this->model_checkout_order->confirm($this->session->data['order_id'], 2);
```

After that I faced no problem in updating order status.

Answer (score 1):

Your order status should be greater than zero because model have this check

```
 $order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "language l ON (o.language_id = l.language_id) WHERE o.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND o.order_status_id > '0'");
```

Comment: yes @zoonman right. The 2nd argument of the API is actually order status id. I'm providing a hard value of "2" already.